# I can t set up a network firewall rule with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

Hi got an issue to turn on a firewall rule :
My goal is to set up a network firewall rule on my public profile for a specific displaygroup with a range of ip networks (variable).

commmand :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps

I ve tried to switch the variable and always the same issue below :

```
$IPAddresses = @('192.168.124.0/22','192.168.125.0/22','192.168.127.0/22','192.168.136.0/22','192.168.138.0/22','192.168.139.0/22')

set-netfirewallrule -DisplayGroup "Recherche du réseau" -Enabled True  -Profile Public -RemoteAddress $IPAddresses -LocalAddress $IPAddresses
```

```
set-netfirewallrule : Impossible de combiner des points de terminaison logiques (tuples de confiance) avec des adresses ou des ports spécifiques.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ set-netfirewallrule -DisplayGroup "Recherche du réseau" -Enabled True ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (MSFT_NetFirewal...ystemName = ""):root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [Set-NetFirewallRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Set-NetFirewallRule
 
set-netfirewallrule : Impossible de combiner des points de terminaison logiques (tuples de confiance) avec des adresses ou des ports spécifiques.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ set-netfirewallrule -DisplayGroup "Recherche du réseau" -Enabled True ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (MSFT_NetFirewal...ystemName = ""):root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [Set-NetFirewallRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070057,Set-NetFirewallRule
```

If someone could help me ^^
Thks

Comment: You can't use the same list of addresses for `-RemoteAddress` *and* for `-LocalAddress`, this does not make sense (that's also what the error message is saying). Try without specifying any `-LocalAddress`, as the ones in your list seem to be remote.

Comment: I tested your script in my sandbox and, despite the errors, it seems to work. Ranges are added in the firewall rules

Comment: I use both localaddress and remoteaddress because i want to apply this rule only to these ip ranges.

Comment: Yes, but these are the *remote* addresses, unless your own PC has its IP address in that range.

Comment: i ve tried just remote adress as option but always the same error.